# Angular + Firebase problema Undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic

tengo un pequeño problema estoy intentado sacar de un Array de números de Firebase, pero me sale Undefined todo el rato.
Estoy trabajando con Angular y Firebase, he intentado a través de un método pero no hay manera..
getNumeros(){

```
    this.db.collection('numeros').doc('9XD7U2wWjUeO3c3BYEEhayAE7Qq1')
    .snapshotChanges()
    .subscribe( res => {
    this.response = (res.payload.data());
    this.response.array.forEach(numeros => 
      console.log(numeros)
    );
  });
 }
```

Esto es la parte de código, el res.payload.data(), me devuelve lo siguiente:
[image: Obtención de datos]

[image: forEach Undefined]

Estoy intentando de otras maneras pero nada.. me sigue saliendo undefined. Alguna sugerencia, básicamente lo único que quiero es obtener los datos del Array.

[image: Array Undefined]

Muchas gracias, un saludo!

Extra, esto me devuelve lo siguiente, quiero poder almacenar el

```
this.response.numeros..
    getNumeros(){
    this.db.collection('numeros').doc('9XD7U2wWjUeO3c3BYEEhayAE7Qq1')
    .snapshotChanges()
    .subscribe( res => {
    this.response = (res.payload.data());
      console.log(this.response.numeros)
  });
  return this.response.numeros
  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos. En la última imagen podrás notar que primero se imprime el console que no esta en el firebase y luego el de este; "acompañalos" de una cadena adicional para que los identifiques c/u. Recuerda que todos es asincrono. Busca el ToPromise o Promise (o similar) para que cada código (digamos) dependiente de un proceso previo se ejecute cuando su antecesor finalice (y desde luego ya tengas el resultado a tratar)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la respuesta de `res.payload.data()` no existe un índice que se llame `array` evidentemente no puedes ciclar de un índice que no existe, el error está en

```
this.db.collection('numeros').doc('9XD7U2wWjUeO3c3BYEEhayAE7Qq1')
    .snapshotChanges()
    .subscribe( res => {
    this.response = (res.payload.data());
    this.response.array.forEach(numeros => // El índice array en this.response no existe
      console.log(numeros)
    );
  });
 }
```

Entonces debería funcionar así

```
this.db.collection('numeros').doc('9XD7U2wWjUeO3c3BYEEhayAE7Qq1')
    .snapshotChanges()
    .subscribe( res => {
    this.response = (res.payload.data());
    this.response.forEach(numeros => 
      console.log(numeros)
    );
  });
```

En tu segundo código, estás retornando un valor, que, aún no está definido, esto pasa cuando utilizas funciones asíncronas. Recuerda que Javascript leerá tu intento de suscribirte a un observable y lo dejará corriendo, mientras continuará con su proceso normal, el problema es que, la siguiente línea es retornar la respuesta del observable que, aún no termina de procesar nada, y por eso te regresa `undefined`. Ahora, si ya estas utlizando variables de alcance de clase, no necesitarías retornar nada, sólo asigna el valor, dentro de la suscripción

```
getNumeros(){
    this.db.collection('numeros').doc('9XD7U2wWjUeO3c3BYEEhayAE7Qq1')
    .snapshotChanges()
    .subscribe( res => {
    this.response = (res.payload.data()); // Aquí ya se asignó globalmente tu respuesta, no necesitas retornar
      console.log(this.response.numeros)
  });
  }
}
```

Si es muy necesario retornar un valor, entoces tu observable deberá pasar por una función `pipe()` y luego por un `map()` para hacer lo que quieres, pero lo veo innecesario.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así

```
    this.response = (res.payload.data()['numeros']);
this.response.forEach(numeros => 
  console.log(numeros)
);
```